# Different values of Stopwatch.Frequency on the same PC

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, frequency, stopwatch

I'm working on online game and have client and server. For client I use Unity3D and C#, server is written in C#. For synchronization I use timers, and as we know timers depends from ticks. Ticks counter in C# is class Stopwatch, and count of ticks in 1 second equals Stopwatch.Frequency, but on server and client, values of Stopwatch.Frequency are different, and it kills my synchronization because the timer on server too slow unlike a timer on the client. Stopwatch.Frequency on the server equals 3.124.980, and Stopwatch.Frequency on the client equals 10.000.000. So why??? How i can change the value of Stopwatch.Frequency for timers synchronization? Thanks and sorry for my bad English

Comment: Can you confirm: is [`IsHighResolution`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.ishighresolution(v=vs.110).aspx) `false` on one and `true` on the other?

Comment: Interesting; in that case, then, you're just going to have to use the lowest frequency, or the greatest common denominator... or any artificial time unit you define

Answer (score 1):

`Stopwatch` can be unreliable on a PC with multiple processors, or processors that do not have a constant clock speed (processors that can reduce clock to conserve energy), so you simply can't use it in a game (because you want it to work in every computer).

Many games uses a global watch, and I've seen that even the simplest global watch algorithm can be good enough to synchronize clients with a server for a game. Take a look at the [Cristian's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cristian%27s_algorithm).

Having a global watch, you can simply use `DateTime.UtcNow` to measure time.

Comment: i answered that almost one month ago!

Answer (score 0):

**StopWatch.Frequency cannot be changed** - it gets the frequency of the timer as the number of ticks per second. This field is read-only.

The timer used by the Stopwatch class **depends on the system hardware and operating system**.

The field **Stopwatch.IsHighResolution** is true if the Stopwatch timer is based on a high-resolution performance counter. Otherwise, IsHighResolution is false, in which case it indicates that the **Stopwatch timer is based on the system timer**.